# How to properly switch Activities in Android?

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter

I'm really not sure how to ask this question but I need a way to allow the user to switch between lists by clicking on them and pressing the 'back' button works naturally.  For instance, I present the users with names of people, they click a name, and a new list appears containing messages from that person.

I'm doing it really poorly right now by having a single `ListActivity` and I use `onListItemClick` to listen for any click on a list.  Then I call `setListAdapter(someArrayList)` each time the list changes.

Surely there is a much more intuitive solution than this. Could someone point me toward some tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need multiple activities, each having their own lists. Then you can start other activities by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit** - parameters for activities can be attached to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity`:

```
intent.putExtra("person", "Bob Smith");
```

and later retrieved in the next activity using:

```
String person = intent.getStringExtra("person");
```

So you would have a `PeopleActivity`, a `MessagesActivity`, etc. and inside that activity the list would only display items pertaining to that type of information.

You might want to check out [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and [Activity and Task Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html) to get a better picture of what's going on when you start new activities.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I tell the MessagesActivity what messages to display relating to the person just clicked?